# How do I shift a prop array on Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm trying to build a post list, and posts are passed down to my component as a prop array. The thing is: I need it to have second and later posts, as the first is shown by another component.

I'm trying to run an array.splice() but as I don't know much about how reactivity is build on Svelte, all ways I've tried or had broke everything or had no effect.

Here's the component, where posts is the array I'm talking about:

```
<script>
import AppBlogPost from "./PostCards/AppBlogPost.svelte";

export let posts;
</script>

<style lang="scss">
</style>

<ul>
  {#each posts as post}
    <AppBlogPost {post} />
  {/each}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To skip the first element in an array you can simply use array destructuring:

```js
let [, ...arr2] = arr
```

This will take your `arr` and write the first element nowhere (the empty space) while writing all the rest to `arr2` using the spread operator.

In the case of Svelte you probably want your post array still be reactive, so you have the mark assignment as such using `$`

```html
<script>
import AppBlogPost from "./PostCards/AppBlogPost.svelte";

export let posts;
$: [, ...otherPosts] = posts
</script>

<ul>
  {#each otherPosts as post}
    <AppBlogPost {post} />
  {/each}
</ul>
```

This also opens up a new possibility, I guess you are using `posts[0]` to display the first post differently ? If you change the reactive statement to `$: [firstPost, ...otherPosts] = posts` you have it in a handy variable instead!

Comment: That `$:`-line is like magic. Really nice way to handle this problem, again I did learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

If members of your `posts` array changes, it won’t be seen by svelte. You have to assign values as new to your `posts` array, then svelte will see the array has been changed.

```
const remove=()=>{
  posts.splice(0,1)
  posts=[...posts]
}
```

Comment: Be aware that it will mutate the original `posts` variable. Better use the answer of [@LionelRowe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8318731/lionel-rowe) with the `spliceImmutable` function.

Answer (score 0):

Svelte detects where re-renders are needed by checking for *assignment* using the `=` operator, not mutation. For example:

```js
// no change detected
const obj = { foo: 1 }
obj.bar = 2

// change detected
let obj = { foo: 1 }
obj = { ...obj, bar: 2 }
```

As for [Array#splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), it:

> changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements **in place**.

That "in place" means it *mutates* the array and *returns* the deleted items.

If you're familiar with the splice API and want to use that, you could build an immutable version on top of it:

```js
const spliceImmutable = arr => (...args) => {
    const clone = [...arr]
    clone.splice(...args)

    return clone
}

let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
arr = spliceImmutable(arr)(2, 1, null) // [0, 1, null, 3, 4]
```

Or use custom logic based on [Array#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) instead (more readable in my opinion):

```js
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
arr = [ ...arr.slice(0, 2), null, ...arr.slice(3) ] // [0, 1, null, 3, 4]
```